# Visual Studio extension to refactor XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, roslyn-code-analysis

I'd like to create an extension for XAML (WPF) which will work like this:

In a XAML file, when you right click on an element tag (i.e.`<Button>`) the context menu will show an option to refactor the element.

What is the general approach for this?
How do I access the element where the cursor is?

Generally, which features from Visual Studio extension development do I need?

Any code examples would be great.

Comment: Did you do any research for this issue? Or you could try to refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-a-command-to-the-solution-explorer-toolbar?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Thanks for reply @hellogood. I have, but the information is scarce. I am looking for some overall idea from someone who did this before.

Comment: Ohh. Thanks. If I find some similar samples further, I will let you know:)